# How to open up access to a directory for a user using setfacl

Tags: linux, shell, chmod, chown

I need to open up access to a directory for given user (user1) in a redhat machine. I'm using the `setfacl` command as follows

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:user1:rwx /var/lib/docker/volumes/logs/_data
```

then I check the access using `getfacl` command and this is what I see

```
user::rwx
user:user1:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:user1:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Comment: This question is off-topic on StackOverflow, it is better asked on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it right.

> Whenever an ACL contains any Default ACL entries, the three Default ACL base entries (default owner, default group, and default others) must also exist.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl

Comment: what does this mean? could you explain more? If I have done it right why I'm getting a permission error then?

Comment: @HHH in your `getfacl` command all ok, you have rwx permissions note to line `user:user1:rwx`